# Can notification channel be declared in XML?

Tags: android, android-notifications

After installing my app, I need to modify some of its specific notification settings (e.g. set specific notification sound).

Before the app programatically creates the relevant notification channel, the setting won't appear in the App Info screen. This means that in order to do what I want I have to run the app at least once.

So the question is, can I declare the notification channel in a way that would display it in App Info even without having to run the app at all?

Answer (score 0):

Notification channels are created when, when notification builder creates the notification.that's why there no way to define the notification channel in XML.

to solve your problem you can generate one notification with your desired channel definition when your app is installed.